# 刚下完雨的地面尚且带着潮湿的水责. Grammatical and translating problam!

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning, sentence-structure, phrase-meaning

刚下完雨的地面尚且带着潮湿的水责.
Well, first of all, do you see the above sentence? Honestly, for example, I know what each of these characters position(grammatically) is in the sentence (except for this part 尚且带着), but whatever I do, I can't translate it correctly.
Can anyone tell me the grammatical position of each character of this sentence and  the correct meanings. finally tell me exactly how the sentence is arranged to give the correct meaning?
Thanks in advance for taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far. You only said "whatever I do, I can't translate it correctly", but maybe some parts you did was correct? Also, it looks like there's a typo here, and perhaps the sentence is unfinished? Please supply the context as well.

Comment: I think it should be 水渍, not 水责．

Comment: I don't think context is necessary here. It's just a straightforward statement of a certain, rather obvious, situation. Since an effort from OP is asked for, I'll not translate it for now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you meant 水渍？

刚下完雨的地面尚且带着潮湿的水渍。
Although the rain had stopped, the ground still showed damp spots.

刚下完雨的地面: just after rain 的 ground
尚且: still
带着: carry
潮湿的水渍。damp 的 water marks

Answer (score 0):

尚且 - ⒈ 副词，表示依旧、仍然。 例如：「躯壳毁灭了，精神尚且存在。」 ⒉ 连词，表示进一层的意思，常与「何况」相应。 引《水浒传·第六三回》：「梁山泊这一伙，朝廷几次**尚且**收捕他不得，**何况**我这里孤城小处？」.

If this is a complete sentence, the first explanation applies. If there is a phrase after it, and the phase contains the word "何况", the second applies. The arrangement/structure of the sentence has no problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is a very simple sentence,which satisfy S-V-O struecture.

地面=subjct

带着=verb

水渍=objct